# Weird result on simple linked list code

Tags: c++, data-structures, singly-linked-list

Okay. I am paying around with a simple linked list code.

I keep the head node as public. then I declare a pointer (head2)to store the head node of the first list(first) in the main program. I declare a second list called second, and assign head2 as the head node of the second list. Then I delete head2. I then access the members of "second" (whose head node is deleted) and print them. I expected a segmentation fault.
But it works, only printing 0 for the data of the head node. What is puzzling to me is that if the head node is deleted, how is the next pointer of the head node still in memory? (this is accessed by print to traverse through the list.I am using g++ 4.6.1 in Ubuntu.Here is the code:

```
#include<iostream>

struct Node
{
    int data;
    Node* next;
};

class list1
{
public:
    list1();
    Node* head;
    void insert(int);
    void print();
};

list1::list1()
{
    head=NULL;
}

void list1::insert(int a)
{
    Node* newnode=new Node;
    newnode->data=a;
    newnode->next=head;
    head=newnode;
}

void list1::print()
{
    Node* dummy=head;
    while(dummy)
    {
        std::cout<<dummy->data<<std::endl;
        dummy=dummy->next;
    }
}

int main()
{
    list1 first;
    first.insert(1);
    first.insert(2);
    first.insert(4);
    first.insert(9);

    list1 second;
    Node* head2=new Node;
    head2=first.head;
    second.head=head2;
    delete head2;
    second.print();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You would do well to google **"C++ undefined behavior"**

Answer (score 2):

Your code invokes undefined behavior by accessing objects whose lifetime is over.

There's nothing strange that it may still work.

Undefined behavior means anything could happen, including what you're observing.

Answer (score 1):

Deleting memory just means returning the memory to system, and returned memory is ready to be allocated again. But data in the memory is still there until the memory is overwritten. Since your program has deleted the memory, and your program don't know when and who will allocate the memory block again. So to your program, still using the memory causes undefined behavior.

Comment: Thanks a lot. That makes it very clear.

Comment: @xkcd83 If I answered your question, please accept my answer by clicking the correct sign. That would add my reputation.